# is it possible to send a form to an external scripting file on a different server other than the one being used by the website?

Tags: php, web-hosting, domain-name

I was wondering if i could easily access my PHP files on a different server other than the one currently being used by my website. I would like to do this so i won't have to give certain scripting files to my client and have the client access them from my own server. If it is possible, how can i set my files' permission so the client can easily access them.

### thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is something called CSRF [Cross Site Request Forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). It is basically a way through which you can prevent what you just asked for: Accept requests from remote forms. But, you **want** to provide this feature. So, instead of directly accepting form POSTs, you can provide an API to selected users you choose to, by  authenticating them before providing them Access. But you will have to write code for the client so that he can use your API.

XML-RPC is *somewhat* related to what you want too. You should check it out.

Comment: It all make perfect sense. but how exactly do i go about to code such API. I have no idea where to begin

Comment: [this](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/how-to-create-an-api-10-tutorials/) should help you.